# GPO Settings Getting Removed time to time

Tags: group-policy

Some of the computer settings that I applied using GPO on client machines are getting removed from time to time, please advise

for example I have created a GPO to add domain admin accounts to local administration group in the client machines,

linked the gpo to the OU and checked the local admin groups, i can see the domain admin accounts

but after few days the domain admin accounts are missing from the local admin group

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have multiple DC servers that are not correctly in sync.

Make sure all DC roles are correctly in sync and that changes correctly propagate to the other DCs.

This can help in finding sync/propagation problems:

```
NetDOM /query FSMO


dcdiag /test:dns

repadmin /showrepl
```

-Post-comment-EDIT-

May be a permission issue then. The policies should propagate under  "NT AUTHORITY\System" no matter the user login status. If it does not happen, there may be a user domain permission problem. Try making the change under another domain admin user.

Comment: thank you and still i haven't found a machine, will update you as soon find one

Comment: checked the event log and found this for the policy that was getting removed
 Group Policy Object did not apply because it failed with error code '0x80090005 Bad Data.' This error was suppressed

Comment: See update; try a different domain admin.